# method with miltiple args - xml-rpc

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I have problem with method with multiple arguments in XML-RPC application. Actually, i have method that sums numbers... and when i'm declaring this method like this:

```
public Integer echo(int x, int y){

    return new Integer(x+y);
```

everything works fine and server gives me the proper answer. But with this:

```
public Integer echo(int... ys) { 
    int res = 0;
    for (int num : ys){
        res=res+num;    
    }
    return new Integer(res);
}
```

I'm having an exception:

> Klient XML-RPC: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: xmlrpcserwer.serwerRPC.echo(int, int)

Am I declaring it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the method signature in the server to :

```
public Integer echo(Object[] ys) { 
  int res = 0;
  for (Object y : ys){
     if (y instanceof Integer){
        res=res+ (Integer) y;    
     }
  }
  return new Integer(res);
}
```

And the invocation in the client using an object array.

I can´t test it but it seems that xmlrpc is looking for a different method signature that the one you have implemented.

https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/types.html